# The effects of reversing the leads of an ammeter

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

I was playing around with a battery, an ammeter, and a light bulb. The ammeter originally read 1.99 A, but after reversing the leads going into and out of the ammeter the ammeter read -1.98A. I know this was because the leads were reversed but I am not sure why reversing the leads led to the ammeter readind a negative value. Why?

Comment: Because it's reading current originating in the other probe.  Indirectly your meter is suggesting the voltage polarity as well as the absolute magnitude of current.

Answer (score 1):

It is showing the direction of current flow reversed through the meter with the reversal of the leads.